# Spring RestTemplate Map specific key value inside JSON response to POJO class

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate, objectmapper

I have an API, which returns JSON in this format:

```
 {
      "errors": null,
      "someKey1": "someValue1",
      "someKey2": "someValue2",
      "response": {
          "id": 21,
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2",
          "key3": "value3",
          "key4": {
              "key5": [
                  {
                      "ABC": "abc",
                      "XYZ": 1,
                      "PQR": "pqr"
                  },
                  {
                      "ABC": "abc",
                      "XYZ": 3,
                      "PQR": "pqr"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "key6": "value6"
      }
    }
```

I also have a POJO class which has fields corresponding to the `response` key of the JSON response because the `someKey1`, `someKey2` and `errors` key are not relevant in my use case.

Is it possible to map the JSON response to my Java POJO class i.e to map only the values inside the `response` key ?

One possible approach is to accept a String response and map it to my POJO using setter methods.

```
String apiResponse = restTemplate.exchange(someUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(authHeader), String.class).getBody();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(apiResponse);
MyObject myObject = buildNewObject(jsonObject.get("response"));
```

Is there a better way. Something like this ? :

```
ResponseEntity<MyObject> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(someUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(authHeader), MyObject.class).getBody().get("response");
```

Comment: I had to make MyObject as a wrapper class which has Response class as a key and then get Response from it, which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Mapper` class with your POJO as one object and other extra values as variables , Shown below

```
class Mapper{

private PojoClass response;
private String someKey1;
private String somekey2;
private String errors;

//Create getters and setters

}
```

Now the `response` will  automatically bind to POJO and other values will  bind to corresponding key1 key2 and errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use getForObject of RestTemplate.

Code Sample:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("USERNAME","PASS");
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(commons);
MyObject myObject = template.getForObject(someUrl,MyObject.class);

public class MyObject  {
    @JsonProperty(value="response")
    private Map<String,String> response;
}
```